# JavaScript transfering one element to another (multiple times) by using event

Tags: javascript, events, button, click, move

I want to transfer multiple times after `click` on "przenieś" the whole `li` from one `div class="listContainer two"` to another, and back again (and again) using JavaScript. How should I prepare the JavaScript code for the most efficient way?

```html
<div class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list1">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list2">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 2 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 2 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So, more specifically you would like to move the li's from list1 to list2 on click?

Comment: Should all of the `<li>` elements - from both lists - be moved to the other list in response to a click or only those elements that originate in `#list2`?

Comment: Yes - to thisiskelvin.

Comment: All - to David Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this. It has no dependencies on jQuery, If you need it to run on older browsers you can change `const` to `var` and change `matches` to checking the targets `className`.

```js
const list1 = document.querySelector('#list1')
const list2 = document.querySelector('#list2')

const swapListItem = function(e) {
  // only continue execution if the target is a .moveBtn
  if (e.target.matches('.moveBtn')) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const item = e.target.parentNode
    const parent = item.parentNode
    parent.removeChild(item)
    if (parent === list1) {
      list2.appendChild(item)
    }
    else {
      list1.appendChild(item)
    }
  }
}
// bind a single event to the window
window.addEventListener('click', swapListItem, false)
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif }
.list { width 40%; float: left; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; color: white }
li { padding: 0.5em }
#list1 { background: #BADA55 }
#list2 { background: #1CE1CE }
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="list1">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 1 <a href="#" class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 1 <a href="#" class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list" id="list2">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 2 <a href="#" class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 2 <a href="#" class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes! I was talikng exactly about that! Now i will try to understan that:D Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Just step through it in the chrome debugger and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="append">click</button>
<div class="list">
  <div class="listContainer two">
    <ul id="list1">
      <li>Item 1 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
      <li>Item 2 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#append').click(function(){
  $html = $('.list > .listContainer').html();
  $('.list').append($html);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what i was thinking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onlclick` listener to your `button`.  Have it run a javascript function that moves the `li` items to the other `ul`.

```html
<div class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list1">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 1 <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(this.parentNode);">PrzenieśMe!</button></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 1 <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(this.parentNode);">PrzenieśMe!</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div  class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list2">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 2 <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(this.parentNode);">PrzenieśMe!</button></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 2 <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(this.parentNode);">PrzenieśMe!</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
function buttonClick(li) {
  var ul = li.parentNode
  var listOfUl = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
  for(var i = 0; i < listOfUl.length; i++) {
     if(listOfUl[i].id != ul.id) {
       listOfUl[i].appendChild(li);
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)! I think it will run too, i will figure it out later :)! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach, taking advantage of ES6 and an experimental JavaScript feature (present in both Chrome and Firefox) `closest()`, is the following:

```
// 'e' is the Event Object, passed from the later use of
// EventTarget.addEventListener():
function moveBetween(e) {

  // we prevent the default action of clicking an <a>
  // Element:
  e.preventDefault();

  // cache a reference to the clicked element (the 'this'
  // is passed from the EventTarget.addEventListener()):
  let clicked = this,

    // here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a
    // NodeList of all elements matching the supplied CSS
    // selector, and Array.from() converts that Array-like
    // NodeList into an Array, to allow us to use Array
    // methods:
    lists = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul')),

    // here we use Array.prototype.filter() to remove those
    // Array elements that do not match the passed argument:
    other = lists.filter(

      // this is an Arrow function syntax, and passes the
      // current Array element (the <ul>) of the Array of
      // elements to the assessment.
      // If the closest ancestor 'ul' is not equal to the
      // current <ul> we retain that <ul>, if the closest
      // <ul> is equal to (and therefore *is*) the current
      // <ul> then we discard that <ul> from the Array:
      list => clicked.closest('ul') !== list
    );

  // if the other Array exists (and is truthy) and it
  // has a length property other than zero (so is also
  // truthy):
  if (other && other.length) {

    // we retrieve the first element of that Array,
    // a <ul> element and use Node.appendChild() to
    // to append the closest ancestor <li> of the
    // clicked element to that <ul>:
    other[0].appendChild(clicked.closest('li'));
  }
}

let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.moveBtn'));

buttons.forEach(
  button => button.addEventListener('click', moveBetween)
);
```

```js
function moveBetween(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let clicked = this,
    lists = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul')),
    other = lists.filter(
      list => clicked.closest('ul') !== list
    );

  if (other && other.length) {
    other[0].appendChild(clicked.closest('li'));
  }
}

let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.moveBtn'));

buttons.forEach(
  button => button.addEventListener('click', moveBetween)
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.moveBtn {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list1">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 1 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="listContainer two">
  <ul id="list2">
    <li>Item 1 z listy 2 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
    <li>Item 2 z listy 2 <a class="moveBtn">Przenieś</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i think it will runs too. :) And I like your explanation :) I will understan how it works too. Because i think this is also a good response.